# Why unable to trigger AWS Lamda function with Coinbase Commerce Webhook on any event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, coinbase-api

I'm trying to connect the Coinbase Commerce Webhook to AWS Lamda function to track the payments related events. But when I try to test the Webhook and send a test request to API endpoint, it just show me a response:

**Hostname uj5x6hdlch.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com resolved to a private, loopback, or otherwise reserved IP**

API type: REST, Authorization: NONE, Method: ANY, Stage: default

But when I try to trigger the same AWS Function from any other source, it works successfully. Also, if I send the test from Coinbase Commerce to any other source (Webhook testing source like this: https://webhook.site/ee429765-f70e-4c09-b830-befb56c34909), then it works successfully.

Steps to Reproduce:
Just Make any Random AWS Function and add its API end point url to Coinbase Commerce Webhook. After Adding it, click on edit and then Send Test.

Thank You

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem? I am also facing the same issue. I tried setting up custom domain as well. But still the issue exist.

Comment: No Bro, I'm still finding the solution and I have no clue about the solution yet.